# SIGABRT signal from gdk_window_get_frame_clock

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, gdk

I am fairly new to GDK/GTK but I'm trying to make some C code thread-safe. (It's quite large otherwise I would post it here.)
I was doing some stress tests and GDB stopped with an error: program received signal SIGABRT, aborted. The program halted in a function called gdk_window_get_frame_clock, which according to the GDK documentation is a low level function for synchronizing screen repainting. The stack trace just shows me "0x0 in ??" for the caller.
Does anyone know what is going on here or where I can start searching? I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Need a bit more information than this. Look at gdb's stack trace to find out what was happening in the bits of code you write when the problem happened, and start there.

Comment: It is not possible to call GTK/GDK function directly from other thread. Are you properly locking all accesses from other threads by `gdk_threads_enter()`/`gdk_threads_leave()` or equivalent functions?

Comment: The application sets itself up by creating a new worker thread to do complex calculations during execution as well as repainting. The main thread handles user interactions. It's almost certainly a race condition.
I'm using POSIX threads and mutex locks to control access to my application variables. I'll try setting up the critical sections and post back when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never draw anything from another thread than the thread containing the glib or gtk main loop. Use `g_idle_add`, `g_timeout_add` or custom hook based on `GSource` to enqueue UI changes from within a secondary thread (those are threadsafe!)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. From what I can tell, GDK 2 allows the gdk_threads_enter/gdk_threads_leave method to lock GDK resources from separate threads. However, GDK 3 does not. Now I'm using g_idle_add to call a function to queue the main window redrawing. It is leading to excessive CPU usage but this is a good starting point.